# Python GTK tray submenu Icon

Tags: python, gtk

I do not program in python, therefore the question. With some help from another post I was able to put this tray menu together, works ok.

How can I set icons to the sub-menu items (appstore, control center, etc)?

Thanks

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk, AppIndicator3 as appindicator

def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new("customtray", "/home/unix/Bin/share/preferences/preferences.03.png", appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(menu())
    gtk.main()

def menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()

    appstore = gtk.MenuItem('AppStore')
    appstore.connect('activate', appStore)
    menu.append(appstore)

    controlcenter = gtk.MenuItem('Control Center')
    controlcenter.connect('activate', CtrlCenter)
    menu.append(controlcenter)

    Separator = gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
    menu.append(Separator)
    
    exittray = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    exittray.connect('activate', quit)
    menu.append(exittray)

    menu.show_all()
    return menu

def appStore(_):
    os.system("deepin-appstore %U")
        
def CtrlCenter(_):
    os.system("dbus-send --print-reply --dest=com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter /com/deepin/dde/ControlCenter com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter.Show")

def quit(_):
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The problem was a gtk config thing: **set_always_show_image(True)**

> controlcenter = gtk.ImageMenuItem.new_with_label('Control Center')
>   controlcenter.set_image(gtk.Image.new_from_file('/home/unix/Bin/share/ddefm.png'))
>   controlcenter.connect('activate', CtrlCenter)
>   **controlcenter.set_always_show_image(True)**   menu.append(controlcenter)